# How to show only one element ande hide other element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to show only one element ande hide other element using javascript ?

When i click on `id="x_1"` i want to show only `id="ele-1"` element and hide other elements

And when i click on `id="x_2"` i want to show only `id="ele-2"` element and hide other elements

And when i click on `id="x_3"` i want to show only `id="ele-3"` element and hide other elements

And when i click on `id="x_4"` i want to show only `id="ele-4"` element and hide other elements

And when i click on `id="x_5"` i want to show only `id="ele-5"` element and hide other elements

And when i click on `id="x_6"` i want to show only `id="ele-6"` element and hide other elements

I don't know how to do that ? thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/a3MKG/63/

```
<script>
function showDiv(data) {  
      $("#ele-"+!data).hide();    
      $("#ele-"+data).toggle();    
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CSS class

```
.active{
    display: inline;
}
```

and add to your press class

```
.press{
    display: none;
}
```

Every div with class "press" will be hidden unless it is has class "active".

When you click a button you just have to add the "active" class to the selected div to show it.

A simple example in Jquery

```
$('div.press').click(function {
    $('.press.active').removeClass('active');
    var divId = //get the id of the div
    $('#'+divId).addClass('active');
});
```

But im sure there are a lot of way to do this, i hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript:
store **id="ele-1"** like id's only **ele-1** in an array. call same function on onclick of every **x_1** like id's along with **ele-1** like text as arguement. In the script, you already have all names stored with id like **ele-1** in array. so with the arguement in the function, create a for loop upto the length of array and set all divs visibility hidden by using this code:

```
for(var i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    if(("ele-"+i)==arguement)
        continue;    
    document.getElementById("ele-"+array[i]).style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

this will set all other elements hidden except the arguement (which is the id of the div to be visible, sent from onclick of x_1 like divs).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created a jsfiddle please have a look. If you need any clarification please ping me. Thanks
[jsFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinnjose/evxoxwjj/)

```css
.press {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.visibleClass {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x_1" class="press" onclick="showDiv('1')">1</div>
<div id="x_2" class="press" onclick="showDiv('2')">2</div>
<div id="x_3" class="press" onclick="showDiv('3')">3</div>
<div id="x_4" class="press" onclick="showDiv('4')">4</div>
<div id="x_5" class="press" onclick="showDiv('5')">5</div>
<div id="x_6" class="press" onclick="showDiv('6')">6</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="ele-1" style="display: none;">show data 1</div>
<div id="ele-2" style="display: none;">show data 2</div>
<div id="ele-3" style="display: none;">show data 3</div>
<div id="ele-4" style="display: none;">show data 4</div>
<div id="ele-5" style="display: none;">show data 5</div>
<div id="ele-6" style="display: none;">show data 6</div>


<script>
  function showDiv(data) {
    $("#ele-" + data).addClass('visibleClass');
    hideElement(6, data);
  }

  function hideElement(total, active) {
    for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
      if (i != active)
        $("#ele-" + i).removeClass('visibleClass');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For using dynamic data please pass number of elements you want to hide in the function hideElement(noOfElements, currentElementNo). If you found this answer helpful please accept the answer. If you want any clarification please ping me with details. Thanks